# Add-AzureADGroupMember memebers show up in AAD group but not in Office.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I ran  Add-AzureADGroupMember to add users to a regular Distribution group. They all show up in AAD when you view the group, but not in Office.com or Exchange. It's been a very long time , how long should it take to sync, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the scenario in my lab and I could see the user that was added to the group within 1-2 mins .

**Command Used:** `Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "GroupObjectID" -RefObjectId "UserObjectID"`

**Reference:** [Add-AzureADGroupMember (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0)

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Replication between AAD and O365 workloads is async and there is no fixed replication time. It is dependent of multiple factors.

If the issue is not resolved then please reach out to azure support by clicking on (help+support) and creating a technical request.